# Android Firebase list data from keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node that stores a list of project keys for each user.

The structure of my `user_projectes` is:

[image]

I have started to play with Firebase for Android and I ended up with this:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("user_projects").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot projectSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("Project","Project Key found: " + projectSnapshot.getKey());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("Chat", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getDetails());
            }
        });
```

Currently what I got are keys for the projects.

I have another node, `projects`, which stores the project data.
The projects data are stored in my `projects/$projectKey` node.

I will also have to populate the project `name` and `photoURL` inside my ListView/GridView.

How I can retrieve the project data for each project key I got and add it to my listview?

Comment: Use `DataSnapshot.getValue()` method. DataSnapshot reference -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

Comment: I need the data from different node.. in this node I strore only keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as @rhari mentions, you do have to make another query....what I've found useful when doing "joins' like this with firebase is to use RxJava...could have something like following for example (which you could use then in your adapter to populate ListView/RecyclerView)

```
public Observable<Project> getProjects(String userId) {
    return getProjectKeys(userId).flatMap(projectKey -> getProject(projectKey));
}
```

Where this falls down is where you want your list to dynamically update as projects are added....in that case you'll need version of listner that has `onChildAdded`/`onChildRemoved` etc and will need then to do lookup of project from those.

Comment: Way better! I've been using RX in javascript, so i'd love to work with RXJava too

Comment: How `getBusinessKeys` should look like?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `MergeWith` or `Zip` instead of `flatMap` to recieve both queryes results and just map them or do whatever you want to do with them. Having in this way both query methods totally not depending of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Just query the database again

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("user_projects").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot projectSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = projectSnapshot.getKey();                         
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("projects").child(key)
               .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                       Project p = snapshot1.getValue();
                   }
               }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("Chat", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a model for your project entity then you can use `Project mProject = projectSnapshot.getValue(Project.class);`

Comment: But.. I have to get the project data from my `projects` node for each key..

Comment: the `projectSnapshot.getKey()` return only the key of the entity, the `projectSnapshot.getValue()` return the values of that entity

Comment: I don't need the value from the `user_projects` node which is just a number, I need all of the project data from `projects` node (name,image,etc)...