# Android Firebase Nested Query

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseListAdapter and trying to get a list of open chat rooms from my Firebase Database, the structure is pretty simple:

[image: Database Structure]

This is what I get when I query:

```
{-KY99IS2mLzayD4HDyd6={location={...}, posts={....} , title="chatname"}
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is to get the data without the ID part, so it would fit my object builder, something like that:

```
{location={...}, posts={....} , title="chatname"}
```

I know that `ChildEventListener` does that, but I don't have an option to use it with the FirebaseListAdapter, so I hope there's another way to do that.

My code is:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatRoom> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatRoom>(this,ChatRoom.class,R.layout.chatslist_row,myRef3) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatRoom chatRoom, int position) {
            System.out.println(chatRoom.title);
        }

    };
```

But it doesn't work because of the key part, it can't use my `ChatRoom` class object builder.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar issue I believe to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802754/android-firebase-list-data-from-keys/40812418#40812418 .

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Actually no, it's different

Comment: the similarity I thought was the existence of nested data that you would have to perform separate query to retrieve....re-reading your question I'm not clear if this is the case or not for issue you're having?

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the id (KY99IS2mLzayD4HDyd6) from the child event listener.
Then made a new database reference with the id (KY99IS2mLzayD4HDyd6) and call for child event listener again.

`mDatabase = databaseRef.getReference("chats/KY99IS2mLzayD4HDyd6");`

if you call `mDatabase` now you will get `{location={...}, posts={....} , title="chatname"}`.

I have solved my issue like that. But not for FirebaseListAdapter. Make your own listview and adapter this might be more flexible.

Comment: Ah, so basically there's no way to do that and I'd need to do that the old way. ok, thanks